# Reload project in runtime on files changing

Tags: scala, sbt, pug

I'm making a little web project with scala, scalate and jade templates. The problem is when i'm changing .scala or .conf files, sbt automatically recompiles them and reloads project, but it doesn't do it when i'm changing my .jade files. All my templates lies under the `pages/` folder in src/main and it is added on the project classpath, also i've added this line to `Build.scala` file in `project/` folder:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories <+= (sourceDirectory)(_ / "pages")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a similar problem. You should change your line in the scala build file on this one:

`unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= (baseDirectory)(_ / "src" / "main" / "pages")`

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! it works. But what's the difference between SourceDir.. and ResourcesDir.. ?